# what is this property of a multivariate function called

Tags: functions, terminology, associativity

Given a multivariate function $f(x), x \in \Re^n$ for any $n$ and any partition of $x = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{m}x_i$, I need

$f(x) = f(x_1, f(x_2, f(x_3, \ldots f(x_m)\ldots)))$

In essence, I have a function that can be appended - meaning, I can compute the function on any subset or partition "recursively" in any order and always get the same final answer.  I know that *sum*, *product*, *min*, and *max* functions all have this property.  Is there a general term for this property of functions?  Are there some other examples other than the 4 I mentioned that also have this property?

Comment: This is *associativity*.  More examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Examples).

Comment: thanks for the answer!